# boot menu usb choice

Tags: boot, usb-installation

I have Ubuntu Desktop on my USB but when I open my boot menu there are multiple things listed to boot from.
==select a boot first device== LS120, +Hard Disk, CDROM, USB-FDD, USB-ZIP, USB-CDROM, USB-HDD, Legacy LAN.
I placed the USB stick in the front of my PC. which one is the correct one to boot from?
*the plus indicates what it is set to as far as I'm aware cause it has windows already installed and I'm trying to swap it for ubuntu desktop.

Comment: When I first tried booting from USB, I thought it would be one of the USB-XXX. But none ever worked. Then with flash drive plugged in I went to Hard Disk. You seem to have a + which would indicate a sub-menu. I would expect that is your correct entry. If newer UEFI system, you will have two entries for USB flash drive, normally. One clearly UEFI as UEFI:xxxx or BIOS as xxxx where xxxx is label or name of flash drive. My system says PMAP which is not the name or label?

Comment: USB-HDD for me.

Comment: On a new (2021) MSI, with a USB to boot, the EFI gives me 3 choices, but the USB choice fails.  I found that interrupting the EFI boot, then immediately trying the EFI menu again gives me four choices, the new item then successfully boots the USB.

Comment: the plus indicates what it is set to as far as I'm aware cause it has windows already installed and I'm trying to swap it for ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Some older BIOSs do not even correctly label USB flash drives in the Boot options. Instead they use some non-standard nomenclature for flash drives like USB-FDD or USB-HDD. USB-FDD stands for "floppy disk drive" which never works with USB flash drives, so in this case you should choose USB-HDD instead. Even though a USB flash drive is not a hard disk drive choosing this option frequently works.

A zip drive is a removable floppy disk storage system that is mostly obsolete like floppy disk drives, so you shouldn't choose the USB-ZIP option either.

Change the boot priority in the BIOS to put USB-HDD first. If that doesn't work disconnect the Windows drive and swap in a replacement hard drive, and your computer will boot from the Ubuntu installer on the USB thumb drive.

Comment: maybe it was what boots from usb most times but unfortunately, it didn't boot into ubuntu desktop and just went back to windows.

Comment: @TCG248 Change the boot priority in the BIOS to put USB-HDD first. If that doesn't work disconnect the Windows drive and swap in a replacement drive and your computer will boot from the USB thumb drive.